# Azure Notification Hub Basic tier device registration: unlimited vs 200,000?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

[image]

- Left one in figure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/
- Right one in figure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/
- My classic portal (below image): *unlimited* shown in registered devices bar chart.

What is the correct understanding for the number of active device registration?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I know, 200K active devices is the limit for basic tier notification hub. We could also find this info at Azure portal.  I will try to report this issue to related team.

[image]

> What is the correct understanding for the number of active device registration?

We could find detailed info at Azure pricing page, here is a snippet:

*What is an Active Device?
Active Devices are devices eligible to receive notifications and are defined as unique registration IDs for devices using Google Cloud Messaging or Amazon Device Messaging, channel URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) for devices using Windows Notification Service or Microsoft Push Notification Service, or device token for devices using Apple Push Notification service.*

Comment: I appended my classic portal display on this post.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're using 10% of the capacity that your current tier offers. You can send push notifications up to 200K active devices on Basic tier.
An active device is a registered device ready to receive your backend notifications.